# HTTPS to HTTP redirect working only for base URL (apache)

Tags: apache, http, https

I have been scratching my head over this for past couple of hours. I need to redirect all the content on my website from https to http.

I added the following code in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Now, this code successfully redirects from https://example.com to http://example.com. But does not redirect https://example/foo.html to http://example/foo.html.
I'm losing way too much traffic due to this.

Thanks.

Comment: check your sub folders where it doesn't work for the existence of other .htaccess files in those folders, and if you have other rules in your main .htaccess file post em as they can affect the outcome

Comment: I just checked, there are no additional .htaccess files in any sub-folder and there are no other rules.

Comment: Does it work if u change it as follow: `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]` Also try using a different browser you haven't used before to ensure you're not cached from previous rules, if it works as expected on the new browser, then switch it to `301`, while testing always use `302` until its working as expected.

Comment: The above code outputs the same result, redirects just the base URL.

Comment: did u use a different browser(you haven't used before) to ensure you had no caching from previous rules

Comment: Yes, all out of options here.

Comment: Then I can only think on the following possibilities, a) you either have a control panel like cPanel or Plesk or similar which have a default redirect set in the panel settings, b) you have a redirection set inside your apache virtualhost for that domain